# Divs to align to bottom and center while sizing

Tags: html, css

I have three divs, all of them have different heights according to the text content within. I have three Read More button on the bottom of each div that I am trying to get to stay the same vertical position across all the bottom of the divs. Also, these Read More buttons need to be centered in the middle no matter how the window is scaled as the divs will float/expand/shrink as the window is adjusted.

Here is what I have so far.
I have everything working but keeping the buttons centered while the window is resizing.

```css
.main {
  float: left;
  min-height: 180px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 30px 0 50 0;
  min-width: 117px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn_learnmore {
  background-color: hsla(358, 13%, 53%, 1.00);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 150px;
  padding: 10px
}

.infoContent {
  max-width: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<div start.container style="position:relative;  " class=main>
  <div start.s class="infoContent" style="">
    <div>Able an hope of body. Any nay shyness article matters own removal nothing his forming. Gay own additions education satisfied the perpetual. If he cause manor happy. Without farther she exposed saw man led. Along on happy could cease green oh. </div>
  </div>
  <div start.s class="infoContent">

    <div>
      Believing neglected so so allowance existence departure in. In design active temper be uneasy. Thirty for remove plenty regard you summer though. He preference connection astonished on of ye. Partiality on or continuing in particular principles as. Do
      believing oh disposing to supported allowance we. </div>
  </div>

  <div start.s class="infoContent">
    <div>On it differed repeated wandered required in. Then girl neat why yet knew rose spot. Moreover property we he kindness greatest be oh striking laughter. In me he at collecting affronting principles apartments. Has visitor law attacks pretend you calling
      own excited painted. Contented attending smallness it oh ye unwilling. Turned favour man two but lovers. Suffer should if waited common person little oh. Improved civility graceful sex few smallest screened settling. Likely active her warmly has.</div>
  </div>
  <div class=btn_learnmore style="left:10%">Learn More</div>
  <div class=btn_learnmore style="left:450px">Learn More</div>
  <div class=btn_learnmore style="left:750px">Learn More</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    .main {
        display: flex;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .btn_learnmore {
        background-color: hsla(358, 13%, 53%, 1.00);
        padding: 10px;
        width: 80px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 450px;
    }

    .infoContent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .infoContent .paragraph {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: justify;
    }

</style>

<div start.container style="position:relative;" class=main>
    <div start.s class="infoContent">
        <div class="paragraph">Able an hope of body. Any nay shyness article matters own removal nothing his forming.
            Gay
            own additions
            education satisfied the perpetual. If he cause manor happy. Without farther she exposed saw man led. Along
            on happy could cease green oh.
        </div>
        <div class=btn_learnmore>Learn More</div>
    </div>
    <div start.s class="infoContent">
        <div class="paragraph">
            Believing neglected so so allowance existence departure in. In design active temper be uneasy. Thirty for
            remove plenty regard you summer though. He preference connection astonished on of ye. Partiality on or
            continuing in particular principles as. Do believing oh disposing to supported allowance we.
        </div>
        <div class=btn_learnmore>Learn More</div>
    </div>

    <div start.s class="infoContent">
        <div class="paragraph">
            On it differed repeated wandered required in. Then girl neat why yet knew rose spot. Moreover property we
            he kindness greatest be oh striking laughter. In me he at collecting affronting principles apartments. Has
            visitor law attacks pretend you calling own excited painted. Contented attending smallness it oh ye
            unwilling. Turned favour man two but lovers. Suffer should if waited common person little oh. Improved
            civility graceful sex few smallest screened settling. Likely active her warmly has.
        </div>
        <div class=btn_learnmore>Learn More</div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very well, but I need to stick a background-color that will cover each of the divs including the Read More Button